# Fail2Ban - I would like to know how to Ban a specific bot recorded in the Nginx access log

Tags: nginx, centos7, fail2ban

I want to Ban a specific bot with Fail2Ban.
Can anyone tell me how?

Here's the Bot you want to ban:.
MJ12bot, AhrefsBot, DotBot, SemrushBot

server environment:.
CentOS7
Nginx

Logs are stored in:.

```
/var/log/nginx/domain-name/access.log
/var/log/nginx/domain-name/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You should edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` to enable the `nginx-botsearch` filter

```
[nginx-botsearch]
enabled = true
```

Then you will have to add your RegEx filters to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-botsearch.conf`

```
# Fail2Ban filter to match web requests for selected URLs that don't exist
#

[INCLUDES]

# Load regexes for filtering
before = botsearch-common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> \- \S+ \[\] \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/<block> \S+\" 404 .+$
            ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (\S+ )?\"\S+\" (failed|is not found) \(2\: No such file or directory\), client\: <HOST>\, server\: \S*\, request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/<block> \S+\"\, .*?$
            HERE_YOUR_NEW_REGEX
ignoreregex = 


# DEV Notes:
# Based on apache-botsearch filter
# 
# Author: Frantisek Sumsal
```

and finally you have to restart the Fail2Ban service

```
service fail2ban restart
```